# Provide resolver override for certain files depending on environment variable

Tags: webpack

I have the need to supply some alternative `.jsx` files depending on a environment variable.

Given this folder structure:

```
(1) src/icons/appIcon.jsx
(2) vendors/foo/src/icons/appIcon.jsx
```

then `import icon from "icons/appIcon"`

should by default import (1).

But when the `APP_VENDOR` environment variable is set to `foo` it should resolve (2).

If `APP_VENDOR` is set to `bar` then file (1) should be resolved, because there is no `vendors/bar/src/icons/appIcon.jsx.

Is this possible to configure with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) against `icons` and then make that point to either `src/icons` or `vendors/foo/src/icons` based on `APP_VENDOR`.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        icons: process.env.APP_VENDOR === 'foo' ?
            path.join(__dirname, 'vendors/foo/src/icons') :
            path.join(__dirname, 'src/icons')
    }
}
```